# Continuous Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory

Today I was speaking with someone about probabilities of continuous random variables. We were discussing the probability of getting any one specific number between zero and one. I was trying to explain that this probability would be zero for any specific number.

I explained it by saying suppose we want to get $\frac{1}{3}$. This would mean that we would need to get $.333\bar{3}$. We could look at it as the probability that we get a 3 in the tenths place and then another in the hundredths and so on. giving us a probability of $\frac{1}{10}^n$ which is zero as the limit goes to infinity. Thus to calculate these probabilities you have to look at whether or not a value falls into an interval and not the probability of getting an exact number.

I was interested in alternative ways to explain this and prove this.

Comment: It's true **by definition**: a continuous random variable is a random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb P(X=x) = 0$ for all $x$.  Presumably what you were really trying to explain is that some particular distribution (uniform on $[0,1]$ perhaps?) is continuous.

Comment: One alternative: show the length of a point is zero and identify a probability measure with length.

Comment: Yes. I do see what you are saying. The length of point I think is a good example! Do you happen to know of where I could find a formal proof for P(X=x)=0 for all x?

I think it is intuitive that the probability of getting any one number exactly would be zero and would be interested in the proof.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140610/infinite-sum-of-random-variables Here you find a formal way of going through your construction.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous) Here, for example in the section "uniformity", you find a proof that the uniform distribution gives probability zero to points.